# What does the "M2" stands for in the new coroutines version(1.3.0-M2)?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I want to update the coroutines version in my build.gradle file and noticed the latest version of coroutines looks like this (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.0-M2). Is it okay to use that as it is or should I use the previous one 1.2.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**M2** means *2nd Milestone Reached*. It should be the build just before Release Candidate and it should be mostly fine but **some bugs might still persist**.

You can use `Version 1.2.2` if you want guaranteed stability